# difference between 人缘儿 and 谈得来

Tags: grammar, meaning, vocabulary, sentence-structure, phrase

What is the difference between these two words, or are they the same?
人缘儿 and 谈得来
Am I supposed to use them at different times?

Answer (score 3):

I would say '有人緣' is used to describe a person, like '他很有人緣' means 'he always gets along well with others'.

'談得來 'is used to describe a relationship, usually used when 'two people' are getting along well, like '我和他很談得來'.

But you could still use '他和大家都很談得來' 'he gets along well with everybody'.

Answer (score 0):

人缘儿 means "popularity" (in a casual situation).

他很有人缘/他的人缘很好 means "He is very popular" or even simpler "He has many friends"

Especial, 他很有女人缘 means "He is very popular among the girls" or simpler "He attracts girls"

---

谈得来 basically means "easy to build a conversation with". So it is about two or a very small group of people. Basically means the mentioned people are close friends and often spend time together.

我跟他谈得来 means "He is the one I'd like to talk to a lot." or simply "he is my close friend."

几个互相谈得来的朋友 means "some close friends"

There is a quotation in Chinese saying "酒逢知己千杯少，话不投机半句多" means, "If I meet a close friend, I can drink thousands of cups of wine while talking to him, but still not satisfied. If I meet a person that I don't like, I feel like speak half a sentence to him is a waste of time." So "talk to a lot" = "close".